# How to get all current running LaunchConfigurations (run- and debugmode) programmatically?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to write an Eclipse plugin which gets all current running LaunchConfigurations (run- and debugmode ones) and terminates them from the back (see img. 1.1).
I know, that there is a `terminate()` method within the class `ILaunchConfiguration`, but I don't think that this is what I'm looking for.

[img. 1.1]
here is an example of LaunchConfigurations (the second and the third are in debugmode), that I want to terminate from last to first. 
[image]

Any help is appreciated as always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the list of current launches from the launch manager and terminate the active processes.

Something like:

```java
ILaunchManager manager = DebugPlugin.getDefault().getLaunchManager();

ILaunch [] launches = manager.getLaunches();

for (ILaunch launch : launches) {
   IProcess [] processes = launch.getProcesses();

   for (IProcess process : processes) {
      if (process.canTerminate()) {
         process.terminate();
      }
   } 
}
```